# Can I instantiate a multi nic vm in a devtest lab environment?

Tags: azure, azure-devtest-labs

Can I have multiple nics and assign them to the devtest lab vm ?
Can I specify the Lab virtual network CIDR ?
Can I set subnet address range ?

Answer (score 0):

Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow!

- Yes, you can attach multiple NICs to a DevTest lab VM, capped at the number supported by the VM size ([Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/sizes?toc=%2Fazure%2Fvirtual-network%2Ftoc.json)/[Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/virtual-machines-windows-sizes?toc=%2Fazure%2Fvirtual-network%2Ftoc.json)).
- Note that the (existing/new) network interface must be in the same virtual network as the VM.
- You can provision subnets with the desired ranges and select any one if you're creating the new NIC.

For example:

[image: Create Network Interface]

Hope this helps.